# opening terminal without logging in

Tags: 14.04, command-line

To install a driver, I need to not have x.org process running. I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> … <kbd>F7</kbd> is supposed to fix it, however <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> brings my computer to an endless black screen, and <kbd>F7</kbd> does absolutely nothing. I need to be able to kill the x.org process while still in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open tty1 via Ctrl+Alt+F1, login and install your driver. To kill the X server isn't necessary. Depending on your system it's pointless, because the server is restarted automatically.

If the installation fails, start the recovery mode via grub menu (hold the left shift key during systems startup), start the network and the root shell and install the driver in this way.

Comment: that could work, but opening tty1 just freezes me on a blank screen, and my grub has never worked

Comment: although, im updating tto 15.04 to see if my installation disk was just broken

Comment: What do you mean with "has never worked"

Comment: this is a very new computer, and the only time ive managed to get in grub was before i was even using a hard drive, im hopeing updating would fix it.

Comment: do you know if theres a way to just fix it through command?

Comment: Start your grub menu by holding the left shift key during system boot. But there is not only one command to repair your system.

Comment: thanks, i think either i did it wrong every other time before or the update fixed it, now that im in the grub menu what do i go to?

Comment: Start the network and select root

Comment: just press c? it says to press c for command line lol

Comment: No that's wrong. Search for something  like "Advanced ..." And start the recovery mode for Ubuntu

Comment: alright now after a stream of codes im in a list of things resume, clean, dpkg, failsafex, fsck, grub, network, root, system-summary.

Comment: Select `network` and after that `root`

Comment: so it automatically put me into a prompt after hitting yes after networking, and its giving me some "ModemManager" warnings about how some device doesnt have a plugin

Comment: i entered the commands i found in that terminal and once i continued the boot the problems i suspected came from the driver are completely fixed, thank you so much for this, i know it took to long cause im new to linux but thank you so much.

Comment: when i rebooted, the red lines all came back.

Comment: Which red lines?

Comment: this is why i thought i needed to update my driver, the screen has little red lines all over it they almost look like repeated semi-colons or exclamation points.

Comment: do you have any idea how else these could be here still, or if i did anything wrong?

Comment: It's too complex to answer this in the comments. You should ask a new question for this.

Comment: done, do you want a link or can u get it through my profile?

Comment: your profile is enough =)

Comment: Wow!  Lots of effort!  Upvoted!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26404/discussion-on-answer-by-a-b-opening-terminal-without-logging-in).